# MySql performs mathematical calculations when inserting PHP Strings

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php `INSERT` for a mysql db that I have a string like a date that "adds" the value instead of just inserting it into the mysql table. When I just echo the value I get `'2012-03'` It's a expiration date and must me formatted this way. But in the data base it shows `'2009'` so it calculates it. What am I doing wrong?

### Here's the insert...

```
<?php
$Last4CCN           = $_POST['CCN'];
$expiration         = $_POST['EXPDATE'];


if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
} 

if (!$conn) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 

mysql_select_db("testing1", $conn);

$last4CCN = mysql_real_escape_string($last4CCN);
$expiration = mysql_real_escape_string($expiration);

$query1 = "
    INSERT INTO payment_profile_id (Last4CCN, CCNExpDate)
    VALUES ($Last4CCN, $expiration)";

if(mysql_query($query1,$conn))
    echo "Update profile_id successfully inserted.<br/>";
else
    echo "Update profile_id encountered an error.".mysql_error();

mysql_close($conn)

//$expiration = mysql_real_escape_string($expiration);

//echo $expiration;
?>
```

Also the MySQL value is varchar(7) for the expdate

Comment: Could you share more of your SQL query?

Comment: can we see the insert statement please?

Comment: Provide your relevant code and table structure please

Comment: What is the type of `CCNExpDate` column?

Comment: It's set as "varchar(7)"

Comment: Bad programmer! SQL Injection will kill you while you sleep!

Comment: @Romain - how do you figure that? Does the method `mysql_real_escape_string($var);` not prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting quotes around the date string. It appears you are inserting the value as integers so mysql thinks it is a math expression and not the string `'2012-03'`.

```
INSERT INTO payment_profile_id (Last4CCN, CCNExpDate)
     VALUES ($Last4CCN, '$expiration')
```

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure how I missed that one. Thanks!

Comment: @Romain what sql injection? if you read the code he posted, the line above the query says `$last4CCN = mysql_real_escape_string($last4CCN);` and `$expiration = mysql_real_escape_string($expiration);`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn What if I set $Last4CCN to `0, 0); DROP TABLE payment_profile_id;`? I understand modern versions of `mysql_query` will not allow it to run, but some old (or possibly buggy) ones would.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to have the MySQL type as type "date" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html